# React - Conditional rendering ( iteration from multiple arrays )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, react-native, iteration

Hi guys currently I have a problem on conditional rendering in react.

I have 2 arrays saved in state :

```
this.state = {
   arr_one:[1,2,3,4,5],
   arr_two:[1,3,5]
};
```

I want to render divs iteration with those array and the condition if items in arr_two exists in arr_one, then render the differents divs.

note : I don't want to fix this with modulus condition (%).

Here's my code :

**Code :**

```
class TestComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arr_one:[1,2,3,4,5],
            arr_two:[1,3,5]
        };
    }


    render() {
        const filteredStyle={
            background:'red'
        }
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
            {
                this.state.arr_one.map((item,index)=>
                    index === this.state.arr_two[index]?
                        <div key={index} className={filteredStyle}>
                            <p>Item {item}</p>
                        </div>
                    : 
                        <div key={index}>
                            <p>I'm not in filter! {item}</p>
                        </div>
                )               
            }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Output :**

> I'm not in filter! 1
>
> I'm not in filter! 2
>
> I'm not in filter! 3
>
> I'm not in filter! 4
>
> I'm not in filter! 5

**Expected Output :**

> Item 1
>
> I'm not in filter! 2
>
> Item 3
>
> I'm not in filter! 4
>
> Item 5

I also have my code demo in 
[**CodeSandBox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-worker-7o509?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the condition `index === this.state.arr_two[index]` using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), to:

```
this.state.arr_two.includes(item)
```

Comment: Thanks aprill, that's what I want Sorry for asking this simple question cos I'm still learning on iteration 

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing index of `arr_one` with value of `arr_two`

And I don't understand during your `arr_one` have value equals 0 but your output isn't

Comment: Yeah edited. and it's actually arrays saved on state 